# How to know if a url is valid for navigating in webbrowser winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a web browser in windows form application based on `webbrowser` control.

I'm trying to make the url address `textbox` for 2 purposes : for navigating and for searching , as in chrome for example .
I added this code :

```
            try
            {
               Uri urlResult = new Uri(urlText.Text);
               webbrowser1.Navigate(urlText.Text);

            }
            catch
            {
               webbrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com/search?q=" + urlText.Text);
            }
```

the problem is that when I enter "youtube.com" for example , this can not be a `Uri` so I get this in google

How to perform this ?
any other suggestions are welcomed 
thanx in advance

Comment: If the string doesn't begin with `http://` or `https://`, try prepending `http://` or `https://`? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried this but with no avail .

Comment: Then try again. Or explain what happened.

Comment: when I enter door for example , and add http:// , this can be a Uri , and I get a message "This program cannot display the webpage"

Comment: Then explain what you would like to happen in the case a user enters an unreachable hostname.

Comment: I want to move to google search for this unreachable hostname,see the catch block above

Comment: Then [handle the error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368612/can-i-detect-errors-while-using-a-net-webbrowser-control).

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** in your current code you are not checking wether the URL is valid or not.you need to first verify wether the given url is reachable or not.

**Solution:** create a seperate function to verify the reachbility of the url if it succeeds then Navigate to the url otherwise open it in google.

Try This:

```
using using System.Net;

private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
        string url = string.Empty;
        string urlProtocol = "http://"; //or https
        if (!urlText.Text.Trim().Contains(urlProtocol))
            url = urlProtocol + urlText.Text;
        else
            url = urlText.Text;
        if (CheckURL(url))
        {
            Uri urlResult = new Uri(url);
            webbrowser1.Navigate(url);
        }
        else
        {
            webbrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com/search?q=" + urlText.Text);
        }

}

bool CheckURL(string url)
{

    var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    bool isURLValid = false;
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    try
    {
        using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
        {
            var location = resp.Headers["Location"];
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
            {
                isURLValid = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        isURLValid = false;
    }
    return isURLValid;  
}
```

Comment: Making a request to verify the request you're about to make is wasting resources.